# Working example of spring watchservicedirectoryscanner

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, microservices

I'm struggling to implement a `WatchServiceDirectoryScanner`. I want to use the scanner to monitor new file uploads to a directory + sub directories. This will exist as part of a Spring boot MVC microservice. I can do this using Java 7's `WatchService` but would prefer a spring file integration style, AOP style

I have it registered as a `@Bea`n in my app config but I'm struggling to figure out how to have it poll and scan a directory and then call... something (a message endpoint?) when a file is detected. Is anyone able to point me in the right direction for even conceptually how this is done. I cannot find an example implementation of this anywhere.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/files.html#_watchservicedirectoryscanner

http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/file/DefaultDirectoryScanner.html#listFiles-java.io.File-

here is my Spring appConfig:

```
public class appConfig {
    @Bean
    public DirectoryScanner scanner() {
        return new WatchServiceDirectoryScanner("/uploads/test");
    }
}
```

Comment: Only adding the bean is going to de exactly nothing. You will need to tie it to a channel to be able to publish the evens/messages and then create something for the other end of the channel that does something with it. The sample is right there in the reference guide, 10 lines above the link you send.

Comment: Yes I understand I need a channel to receive the messages (i mentioned 'message endpoint' above) and its exactly what I'm stuck on. I'm looking again into it now thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
   # create one configuration file and bind an input file channel here

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
        xmlns:int-file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
        xmlns:int-mail="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail"
        xmlns:int-stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail/spring-integration-mail.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

        <int:annotation-config />
            <int:channel id="cfpFileIn"></int:channel>
    <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="cfpFileIn"
            directory="${cfp.flight.data.dir}" auto-startup="true" scanner="csvDirScanner">
            <int:poller fixed-delay="${cfp.flight.data.dir.polling.delay}"></int:poller>
        </int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
    <bean id="csvDirScanner"
            class="org.springframework.integration.file.WatchServiceDirectoryScanner">
            <constructor-arg index="0" value="${cfp.flight.data.dir}" />
            <property name="filter" ref="csvCompositeFilter" />
            <property name="autoStartup" value="true" />
        </bean>

    <bean id="csvCompositeFilter"
            class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter">
            <constructor-arg>
                <list>
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.SimplePatternFileListFilter">
                        <constructor-arg value="*.csv" />
                    </bean>
                    <ref bean="persistentFilter" />
                </list>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>

    <bean id="persistentFilter"
            class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter">
            <constructor-arg index="0" ref="metadataStore" />
            <constructor-arg index="1" name="prefix" value="" />
            <property name="flushOnUpdate" value="true" />
        </bean>

    <bean name="metadataStore"
            class="org.springframework.integration.metadata.PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore">
            <property name="baseDirectory" value="${metadata.dir}"></property>
        </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer as well

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersInvalidException;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRestartException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
public class BatchJobScheduler  {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BatchJobScheduler.class);
    @Autowired
protected JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "job")
    private Job job;

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "cfpFileIn")
    public void run(File file) {
        String fileName = file.getAbsolutePath();
        logger.info("BatchJobScheduler Running #################"+fileName);
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addString(
                "input.file", fileName).toJobParameters();


        try {

            JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job,
                    jobParameters);
            logger.info(" BatchJobScheduler Exit Status : " + execution.getStatus() +"::"+execution.getAllFailureExceptions());

        } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException
                | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException
                | JobParametersInvalidException e) {
            logger.error(" BatchJobScheduler Exit Status : Exception ::",e);
        }
    }
}
```